# YouTube PlayerにオーバーレイしてViewを表示したい

Tags: android, youtube-player-api

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Mata.YTplayer&hl=ja
このアプリのように､YouTube動画の再生画面の上にToolbarなどのViewを､オーバーレイして表示したいです｡  しかし､`YouTube Player API`([URL](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary?hl=ja))を使うと､ToolbarなどのViewをオーバーレイした時に､以下のエラーがでてできません｡

**エラー**

```
YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{1b111527 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1200,128 #7f090047 app:id/toolbar}. The view is inside the YouTubePlayerView, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 547..
```

どうすれば上のアプリのような再生画面を実現できるのでしょうか､デバイスモニタでViewを確認したのですが､やり方がわからないので教えていただけると有難いです｡  よろしくおねがいします｡

Comment: YouTube Player APIを埋め込んでいるコード、およびレイアウトXMLがどのように記述されているのかわからないので、回答のしようがありません。